# Ошибка: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener, при попытке подключения к БД

Tags: python, oracle

Работаю в Ubuntu и пытаюсь подключится к БД в следующем коде:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "welcome", 
"127.0.0.1/orclpdb1")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
   SELECT first_name, last_name
    FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = :did AND employee_id > :eid""",
    did = 50,
    eid = 190)
for fname, lname in cursor:
    print("Values:", fname, lname)
```

При запуске скрипта получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "orcl.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "welcome", 
"127.0.0.1/orclpdb1")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Эээээ. Инстанс и листенер оракла подняты на локальном хосте?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov Не совсем понял ваш комментарий - а на каком хосте их надо поднимать?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду - на локальном

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня тоже самое:

```py
>>> connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "hr", "localhost/pdb1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

```
$ oerr ora 12541
```

> 12541, 00000, "TNS:no listener"
>   // *Cause: The connection request could not be completed **because the listener
>   is not running**.

Слушатель не запущен. Под ОС пользователем, который устаналиввал БД, запустил:

```
$ lsnrctl start
```

И повторил попытку соединения (см. выше):

```
>>> connection
<cx_Oracle.Connection to hr@localhost/pdb1>
```

Comment: Я перенес приложение с oracle  в докер. Там та же самая проблема. Нету утилиты lsnrctl. В $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin лежит только README

Comment: Должна быть, вы не там смотрите.  Тут $ORACLE_HOME/bin.

Comment: Не очень ясно где найти эту утилиту внутри докера. На сайте oracle сказано так - после описания dockerfile : The new image can be used as the basis for your application.     В bin лежат такие утилиты adrci  genezi  sqlplus

Comment: а этот образ вообще точно для сервера ? есть подозрения что это просто клиент

Comment: В комментарии выше уже показал, где искать. Не совсем понимаю, что вы делаете. _Я перенес приложение с oracle в докер_ - какое приложение?

Comment: _а этот образ вообще точно для сервера ?_ - этот, это какой?

Comment: Я хочу из питона подключиться к бд oracle

Comment: Для которого выше приведен докерфайл

Comment: 1) Не надо изменять вопрос после того, как вым дали ответ!!! Это не по правилам данного сайта.  2) oracle/instantclient:19 - это клиент. 3) А где у вас база данных стоит?

Comment: Я его подкорректировал что бы было ясно о чем идет речь. Суть вопроса не изменилась. Я почему то решил что oracle/instantclient:19 - это образ с уже установленной базой данных

Comment: Суть вопроса изменилась почти полностью.  Повторюсь, так где же стоит БД? Или вы пытаетесь подключится к БД которой вообще нету?

Comment: Да, я пытаюсь подключиться к бд которой нет.  Я полагал что образ в oracledocker - это сервер бд. Я планировал разместить на одной машине сервер и приложение которое работает с бд. Я понял что ошибся.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда давайте сделаем так: в первой версии это был вполне нормальный вопрос хорошего качества. Не важно, что он вам конкретно не помог, поможет кому то ещё, это часто случается, что прослушку забывают включить.  Откатим изменения к первоой версии. Затем, вы поставите сервер в образ докера, и если возникнут проблемы, то вы просто зададите новый вопрос. Как вам такой вариант?

Comment: да,хорошо, сделаем так